# How to use an element multiple times in a single view + cakephp

Tags: cakephp, view, cakephp-2.0

I am having a view and an element. In my cakephp code i am using the element for the first time in my views and it works as expected. but i want to use the same element for the next two time in the same form of the view and its not working at all.
This is my view:

```
<div class="add form">
<?php echo $this->Form->create('add name', array('class'=>'form-horizontal'));?>
<fieldset>
<legend>
<?php echo __('Add Name'); ?>
</legend>
<?php
echo $this->Form->input('name');
echo $this->Form->input('numeric_id');
echo $this->Form->input('parent_id', array('options' => $parents));
?>
<div>
<?php echo $this->element('editortoolbar'); ?>
<?php echo $this->Form->label('Your Description');?>
    <div id="editor" contenteditable=true></div>
</div>
<?php echo $this->Html->script('hotways'); ?>
<?php echo $this->Html->script('welsubs'); ?>
<?php echo $this->Html->script('application');?>
<?php echo $this->Form->hidden('description',array('id'=>'desc'));?>
<!-- == EDITOR END == -->
<hr>
</fieldset>
<?php echo $this->Form->button(__('Submit'), array('class'=>'btn btn-primary'));?>
<?php echo $this->Form->end();?>
</div>
<script>
    $('#editor').live('keyup',function () {
    var value = $(this).html();
    $('#desc').attr("value",value);
}).keyup();
</script>
```

now this is the part of code  i want to reuse in this same form for two times for another different kind of descriptions.

```
<?php echo $this->element('editortoolbar'); ?>
    <?php echo $this->Form->label('Your Description');?>
        <div id="editor" contenteditable=true></div>
    </div>
    <?php echo $this->Html->script('hotways'); ?>
    <?php echo $this->Html->script('welsubs'); ?>
    <?php echo $this->Html->script('application');?>
    <?php echo $this->Form->hidden('description',array('id'=>'desc'));?>
```

editortoolbar is my element  that has various buttons. this is the screen shot of the code:
[image]

now this toolbar works for all the div having id='editor'. but in this form i want to use this toolbar for 3 div. and i am not getting any approach to do this.

Any idea or any suggestion please help.

Comment: *"now this toolbar works for all the div having id='editor'"*... but only one div can have that id

Comment: no this works for only the first div in the view.

Answer (score 0):

Well, you are attaching the action to an id, and the id clearly can have it just the one element.

```
<script>
    $('#editor').live('keyup',function () {
        var value = $(this).html();
        $('#desc').attr("value",value);
    }).keyup();
</script>
```

That will only work for one instance of the element. If you plan on using multiple elements, then you need to identify them in another way. I can give you a suggestion based on classes, but you're gonna need to adjust the action executed by the javascript depending on what it's supposed to do.

Add a class identifier to the element

```
<?php echo $this->element('editortoolbar'); ?>
<?php echo $this->Form->label('Your Description');?>
    <!-- here, add the class -->
    <div class="editorclass" contenteditable=true></div>
</div>
```

and change the script to something like

```
<script>
    $('.editorclass').live('keyup',function () {
        var value = $(this).html();
        $('#desc').attr("value",value);
    }).keyup();
</script>
```

Now, you have a `#desc` reference that is also not going to work because it's referenced by id. So you can approach that by doing the same thing, changing ids for classes, but you're gonna need to find a way to keep together that editor class with that description. What I normally do for this cases is count the elements that have the same class, identify the index of the element been referenced, and modify the other class (in this case the description) with the same index. In your case it would be something similar to

```
<script>
    $('.editorclass').live('keyup',function () {
        var value = $(this).html();
        $('.descclass').eq($('.editorclass').index($(this))).attr("value",value);
    }).keyup();
</script>
```

But I haven't tested so you need to adjust that function. Oh, you will need to change this part also

```
<?php echo $this->Form->hidden('description',array('class'=>'descclass' ));?>
```